# 各アルゴリズムの正解率を確かめるで、fitでエラーになります: TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, python3

以下のコードで色々試してもエラーになります。引数を指定してくださいとも出ますが、どこでどれに何の引数を渡せばいいのか分かりません。
どなたかアドバイスお願いします。

**ソースコード**

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

from sklearn.utils import all_estimators

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

# アヤメデータの読み込み
iris_data = pd.read_csv("iris.csv", encoding="utf-8")

# アヤメデータをラベルと入力データに分離する
y = iris_data.loc[:,"Name"]
x = iris_data.loc[:,["SepalLength","SepalWidth","PetalLength","PetalWidth"]]

# 学習用とテスト用に分離する
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.2, train_size = 0.8, shuffle = True)

# classifierのアルゴリズム全てを取得する --- (*1)
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
allAlgorithms = all_estimators(type_filter="classifier")

for(name, algorithm) in allAlgorithms:
    # 各アリゴリズムのオブジェクトを作成 --- (*2)
    clf = algorithm()

    # 学習して、評価する --- (*3)
    clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
    y_pred = clf.predict(x_test)
    print(name,"の正解率 = " , accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

**実行結果**

```
AdaBoostClassifier の正解率 =  0.9333333333333333
BaggingClassifier の正解率 =  0.9333333333333333
BernoulliNB の正解率 =  0.3
CalibratedClassifierCV の正解率 =  0.9
CategoricalNB の正解率 =  0.9666666666666667
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/fujiokamasaya/PycharmProjects/project/test2.1.py", line 27, in <module>
    clf = algorithm()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'base_estimator'


プロセスは終了コード 1 で完了しました
```

Comment: プログラムの実行方法を把握されていないようにも見えますが、このコードはご自身で書いたものでしょうか？ / もし第三者が公開されている物などを利用している場合には、出典も質問文に明記してください。

Comment: 書籍に掲載されている物をコーディングしています。

Comment: 何かしら他のものを参考にした場合、(1) 著作権上の問題が出ないよう引用などの方法をとる (2) 回答者が質問の文脈を把握しやすくする……ために、質問文の中に何を参考にされたのか書いていただきたいです。質問文下の「編集」から追記できますので、どうぞよろしくお願いいたします<(\_ \_)>

Answer (score 1):

参考にされた書籍に載っていたプログラムがライブラリのアップデートを考慮していなかったか、この部分に対する対処が書籍に載っているけれど読み落としているかどちらかなのではないかと思います。

scikit-learn 0.22.1 で試したところ、`all_estimators(type_filter="classifier")` は次の順番で出力していました。

- AdaBoostClassifier
- BaggingClassifier
- BernoulliNB
- CalibratedClassifierCV
- CategoricalNB
- ClassifierChain
- ...

今回エラーが出ているのはおそらく [`ClassifierChain`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.ClassifierChain.html) に対して `__init__()` を実行しようとしたからでしょう（`clf = algorithm()` の行です）。`ClassifierChain` は初期化時に必ず `base_estimator` オプションが必要ですが、このプログラムでは引数を何も渡していません。

対処法ですが、そもそも様々な分類器に対して一挙にループを回して分類しようとしているのがやや無理がありそうです。場当たり的な対処としては何かしらエラーが出る度にその分類器を回避する if 文を付け加えるのが考えられます。たとえば下のように単にスキップしたり、あるいは他の処理をしたりなどです。

```
for(name, algorithm) in allAlgorithms:
    if name == 'ClassifierChain':
        continue

    # 各アリゴリズムのオブジェクトを作成 --- (*2)
    clf = algorithm()

    # ...
```